# Error on Logging in Still prompts but still Logs in

Tags: android

I am developing a mobile application that has 2 types of users.

In my php code, I separated the boolean for each user. `success` for the client and `success1` for the stylist.

When I press log in, the error prompts first following is the fast intent for the successful menu profile.

This is my line of codes from `LoginRegister.java`

```
private ProgressBar loading;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    final EditText userLoginUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
    final EditText userLoginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPass);
    final Button Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    final Button Register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    loading = findViewById(R.id.loadinglogin);

    //login
    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String username = userLoginUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = userLoginPassword.getText().toString();

            if(!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                Login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            boolean success1 = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success1");

                            //Client's Log in
                            if (success) {

                                    //gikan sa php (green ones) to strings sa android
                                    String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                                    String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                    String number = jsonResponse.getString("number");
                                    String gender = jsonResponse.getString("gender");
                                    String address = jsonResponse.getString("address");
                                    String occupation = jsonResponse.getString("occupation");
                                    String birth_date = jsonResponse.getString("birth_date");
                                    String user_type = jsonResponse.getString("user_type");

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginRegister.this, ProfileActivity.class);

                                //from strings to pass sa lain intents.
                                intent.putExtra("username",username);
                                intent.putExtra("number",number);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                intent.putExtra("gender", gender);
                                intent.putExtra("address", address);
                                intent.putExtra("occupation", occupation);
                                intent.putExtra("birthDate", birth_date);
                                    intent.putExtra("userType", user_type);

                                    LoginRegister.this.startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();

                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginRegister.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed! Please provide valid username and password or connect to internet.")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                                Login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }

                            //Stylist's Log in
                            if(success1) {

                                    String user_type = jsonResponse.getString("user_type");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginRegister.this, ProfileActivity.class);

                                intent.putExtra("userType", user_type);

                                LoginRegister.this.startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginRegister.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed! Please provide valid username and password or connect to internet.")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                                Login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginRegister.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);
            }else if(username.isEmpty() ){
                userLoginUsername.setError("Please insert a username");
            }else if(password.isEmpty()){
                userLoginPassword.setError("Please put your password");
            }

        }
    });

    //register
    Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Register = new Intent(LoginRegister.this, RegisterCustomerOrStylist.class);
            LoginRegister.this.startActivity(Register);


        }
    });

}
```

PS they have different datas from different tables. What I did is that I have an if condition that if the boolean of `success` (client) is true, it passes the data and its else is the `alertdialog` for error login. After it is another if statement for the `success1` (stylist) which has the same logic with client.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you: Please don't use capital letter for the first alphabet of a variable. Like you have used `Intent Register`, but for better readability and use, it should be `Intent register`. Please have a look at all those.

Comment: okay thank you sir. I still have my problem ongoing sir. I'm really trying to solve the logic error.

Comment: I just gave you a suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If simplified, your code looks like this.

> ```
> //Client's Log in
> if (success) {
> } else {
>     AlertDialog.Builder builder = ...
> }
>
> //Stylist's Log in
> if(success1) {
> } else {
>     AlertDialog.Builder builder
> }
> ```

This means if a stylist tries to log in, client's log in block alert dialog will be shown, and vice versa.

So, a flag may be needed to check any success exists.

```
boolean successAny = success || suucess1;

//Client's Log in
if (success) {
} else {
    if (!successAny) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = ...
    }
}

...
```

NB. A person is a client and also be a stylist case is not intended for this sample.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed sir! thank you so much!